# hibernate: How to read a set of enums stored in an array as custom codes

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Subj is the question. Let me invite you to dive into some context. I make a brand-new DB containing the single table and fill that table with the single row:

```
create table schedule (
  id int generated by default as identity (start with 100) primary key,
  days_of_week char(3)[] not null check (true/*
    here I unsure that days_of_week is a unidimensional
    and it's not empty
    and its length is equal to the length of an array
    filled with unique values of days_of_week values only
  */)
);

insert into schedule (id, days_of_week) values
(0, array['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']);
```

...spawn the entity class (mixing lombok)

```java
@Entity @Data
public class Schedule {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
}

public interface ScheduleRepository
extends CrudRepository<Schedule, Integer> {}
```

..and execute this setting with:

```java
@Bean
CommandLineRunner printAllSchedules(ScheduleRepository repository) {
  return args -> {
    for (Schedule schedule : repository.findAll()) {
      log.info(schedule.toString());
    }
  };
}
```

Finally, I get:

```
213347.962 I main/Application : Schedule(id=0)
```

Voilà! Now I add the missing attribute to my entity:

```java
@Entity @Data
public class Schedule {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  private Set<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek;
}
```

It fails (expectedly):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to
  extract JDBC value for position `2`
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to extract JDBC
  value for position `2`
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast
  to class java.lang.Number (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in module
  java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Aha, just a moment:

```java
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Set<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek;
```

Run and get a different result:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to
  extract JDBC value for position `2`
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to extract JDBC
  value for position `2`
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
  java.time.DayOfWeek.mon
```

Obviously, it reads the array from `days_of_week` column and tries to convert `mon` into any `DayOfWeek`, and it fails expectedly. Let's try to put in the table «correct» strings for days of week:

```
alter table schedule
alter column days_of_week
set data type varchar(9)[];

update schedule
set days_of_week = array['SUNDAY', 'MONDAY']
where id = 0;
```

...and run:

```
215032.322 I main/Application : Schedule(id=0, daysOfWeek=[MONDAY, SUNDAY])
```

Now, let's add this column:

```
alter table schedule
add column having_sex_day char(3)
not null default 'fri';
-- today, January 13, 23 is Friday, not what you thought,
-- and sex is what I'm doing right now here, not what you thought
```

...touch the entity too:

```java
@Entity @Data
public class Schedule {
  // ...
  @Convert(converter = DayOfWeekConverter.class)
  private DayOfWeek havingSexDay;
}

@Converter
public class DayOfWeekConverter
implements AttributeConverter<DayOfWeek, String> {
  private static final Map<DayOfWeek, String> ENUM_ABBR = new HashMap<>(7, 1F);
  private static final Map<String, DayOfWeek> ABBR_ENUM = new HashMap<>(7, 1F);
  static {
    for (DayOfWeek i : DayOfWeek.values()) {
      String abbr = i.name().substring(0, 3).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
      ENUM_ABBR.put(i, abbr);
      ABBR_ENUM.put(abbr, i);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(DayOfWeek attribute) {
    return ENUM_ABBR.get(attribute);
  }

  @Override
  public DayOfWeek convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    return ABBR_ENUM.get(dbData);
  }
}
```

...and run:

```
215956.497 I main/Application : Schedule(id=0, daysOfWeek=[MONDAY, SUNDAY], havingSexDay=FRIDAY)
```

Okay, guys, the final stroke: Now I want Hibernate to read daysOfWeek written as three-letter abbreviations using the same converter:

```java
@Entity @Data
public class Schedule {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  @Convert(converter = DayOfWeekConverter.class) // <-- IDE warns me here
  private Set<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek;
  @Convert(converter = DayOfWeekConverter.class)
  private DayOfWeek havingSexDay;
}
// The warning says: Converter's type DayOfWeek doesn't match
// with the attribute type Set<DayOfWeek>. I know, bro, I know
```

...update the table:

```
update schedule
set days_of_week = array['sun', 'mon']
where id = 0;
```

...results in:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to
  extract JDBC value for position `2`
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to extract JDBC
  value for position `2`
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
  java.time.DayOfWeek.mon
```

again. Surrendering I make this change:

```java
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DayOfWeekConverter
implements AttributeConverter<DayOfWeek, String> {
  // ...
}
```

...which yields the same result.

Please, help me move back and forth, back and forth days of weeks stored abbreviated in an array.

Thank you!

---

**UPD:** @EricGeorge, [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75113935/2634207) to try an `@ElementCollection`. `@ElementCollection` is for values stored in a different table (relation), not in an array column. But I tried anyway:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
  JDBC exception executing SQL [select d1_0.schedule_id,d1_0.days_of_week
  from schedule_days_of_week d1_0 where d1_0.schedule_id=?]; SQL [n/a]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing
  SQL [select d1_0.schedule_id,d1_0.days_of_week from schedule_days_of_week d1_0
  where d1_0.schedule_id=?]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
  ERROR: relation "schedule_days_of_week" does not exist
```

Expected. Sorry, Eric ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an `@ElementCollection` annotation:

```
@Entity @Data
public class Schedule {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass=java.time.DayOfWeek, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Convert(converter = DayOfWeekConverter.class) 
  private Set<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek;

  @Convert(converter = DayOfWeekConverter.class)
  private DayOfWeek havingSexDay;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I tried. Doesn't work. I appended the result to my original text. Thank you again